# Typesetting similar to Annals

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I wanted to use the same fonts that are used in the Annals of Mathematics since I find the typesetting clear and beautiful. However, when I try to check what fonts are used I get many types. Mainly acronyms starting with CM (CMMI, etc) which makes me think they are mainly variations of Computer Modern. It is also claimed on the MathTime Pro website that they are using mtpro 2, which is puzzling because it doesn't look like it to me. Can anybody explain how I can get those fonts and those settings (I mean the Annals')?

Comment: From a randm paper I downloaded from jtstor it looks like normal CM.

Comment: Can you guess other packages that are used e.g. for the format of the page, and the titles? I am really looking to know as much as I can about what they use. Also: why does MathTime pro claim that the Annals use their font?

Comment: According to their web page they use the class `aomart`, which is part of TeXLive.